# How to disable Scroll Trigger on scroll up gsap ScrollTrigger?

Tags: javascript, gsap

I have a simple page with gsap and ScrollTrigger animation:

```js
function animateFrom(elem, direction) {
  direction = direction || 1;
  var x = 0,
    y = direction * 100;
  if (elem.classList.contains("gs_reveal_fromLeft")) {
    x = -100;
    y = 0;
  } else if (elem.classList.contains("gs_reveal_fromRight")) {
    x = 100;
    y = 0;
  }
  elem.style.transform = "translate(" + x + "px, " + y + "px)";
  elem.style.opacity = "0";
  gsap.fromTo(elem, {
    x: x,
    y: y,
    autoAlpha: 0
  }, {
    duration: 1.5,
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    autoAlpha: 1,
    ease: "expo",
    overwrite: "auto"
  });
}

function hide(elem) {
  gsap.set(elem, {
    autoAlpha: 0
  });
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

  gsap.utils.toArray(".gs_reveal").forEach(function(elem) {
    hide(elem); // assure that the element is hidden when scrolled into view

    ScrollTrigger.create({
      trigger: elem,
      markers: false,
      onEnter: function() {
        animateFrom(elem)
      },
      // onEnterBack: function() { animateFrom(elem, -1) },
      // onLeave: function() { hide(elem) } // assure that the element is hidden when scrolled into view
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.gs_reveal {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  will-change: transform, opacity;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-SbiR/eusphKoMVVXysTKG/7VseWii+Y3FdHrt0EpKgpToZeemhqHeZeLWLhJutz/2ut2Vw1uQEj2MbRF+TVBUA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.11.5/gsap.min.js" integrity="sha512-cOH8ndwGgPo+K7pTvMrqYbmI8u8k6Sho3js0gOqVWTmQMlLIi6TbqGWRTpf1ga8ci9H3iPsvDLr4X7xwhC/+DQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.11.5/ScrollTrigger.min.js" integrity="sha512-AMl4wfwAmDM1lsQvVBBRHYENn1FR8cfOTpt8QVbb/P55mYOdahHD4LmHM1W55pNe3j/3od8ELzPf/8eNkkjISQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="py-5">
    <h1 class="gs_reveal text-center">Scroll down and up to see different reveal animations</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="">
    <div class="row py-5">
      <div class="col-5 gs_reveal gs_reveal_fromLeft">
        <div class="d-block">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/479/479?index=1" alt="" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-7">
        <h2 class="gs_reveal">Create amazing svg animations</h2>
        <p class="gs_reveal">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis quia doloribus, inventore rem, at pariatur asperiores minus qui accusantium quod nisi! Modi eveniet eaque enim totam deserunt dolores alias aliquid.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row py-5">
      <div class="col-7 text-end">
        <h2 class="gs_reveal">Supercharge immersive WebGL experiences</h2>
        <p class="gs_reveal"> Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam praesentium numquam fugiat consequatur aliquid eos assumenda natus deserunt eum doloribus quia mollitia omnis, voluptatem maiores dicta exercitationem veritatis magnam iusto in
          officiis reiciendis ipsum, delectus maxime? Sit eligendi temporibus dolores? </p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-5 gs_reveal gs_reveal_fromRight">
        <div class="d-block">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/479/479?index=2" alt="" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row py-5">
      <div class="col-5 gs_reveal_fromLeft">
        <div class="block">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/479/479?index=3" alt="" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-7 text-start">
        <h2 class="gs_reveal">Control performant Canvas animations</h2>
        <p class="gs_reveal"> Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore nulla natus minus praesentium, adipisci quam distinctio recusandae accusamus similique aut velit iusto reprehenderit deleniti! Nobis?</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row py-5">
      <div class="col-7 text-end">
        <h2 class="gs_reveal">Award winning websites</h2>
        <p class="gs_reveal"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem vero temporibus deleniti qui rem ipsa! </p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-5 gs_reveal gs_reveal_fromRight">
        <div class="d-block">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/479/479?index=4" alt="" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

[CodePen][1]

But when I scroll up and then down again, does the animation repeat? How I can fix it, when I scroll up and then down again, shouldn't the animation repeat?

**Question:** How to disable Scroll Trigger on scroll up gsap ScrollTrigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `animateFrom` is called every time the section is entered.

You’ll need to flag it as already played.

```js
function animateFrom(elem, direction) {
  if (elem.played === true) {
    return;
  }
  elem.played = true;
  direction = direction || 1;
  var x = 0,
    y = direction * 100;
  if (elem.classList.contains("gs_reveal_fromLeft")) {
    x = -100;
    y = 0;
  } else if (elem.classList.contains("gs_reveal_fromRight")) {
    x = 100;
    y = 0;
  }
  elem.style.transform = "translate(" + x + "px, " + y + "px)";
  elem.style.opacity = "0";
  gsap.fromTo(elem, {
    x: x,
    y: y,
    autoAlpha: 0
  }, {
    duration: 1.5,
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    autoAlpha: 1,
    ease: "expo",
    overwrite: "auto"
  });
}

function hide(elem) {
  gsap.set(elem, {
    autoAlpha: 0
  });
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

  gsap.utils.toArray(".gs_reveal").forEach(function(elem) {
    hide(elem); // assure that the element is hidden when scrolled into view

    ScrollTrigger.create({
      trigger: elem,
      markers: false,
      onEnter: function() {
        animateFrom(elem)
      },
      // onEnterBack: function() { animateFrom(elem, -1) },
      // onLeave: function() { hide(elem) } // assure that the element is hidden when scrolled into view
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.gs_reveal {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  will-change: transform, opacity;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-SbiR/eusphKoMVVXysTKG/7VseWii+Y3FdHrt0EpKgpToZeemhqHeZeLWLhJutz/2ut2Vw1uQEj2MbRF+TVBUA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.11.5/gsap.min.js" integrity="sha512-cOH8ndwGgPo+K7pTvMrqYbmI8u8k6Sho3js0gOqVWTmQMlLIi6TbqGWRTpf1ga8ci9H3iPsvDLr4X7xwhC/+DQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.11.5/ScrollTrigger.min.js" integrity="sha512-AMl4wfwAmDM1lsQvVBBRHYENn1FR8cfOTpt8QVbb/P55mYOdahHD4LmHM1W55pNe3j/3od8ELzPf/8eNkkjISQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="py-5">
    <h1 class="gs_reveal text-center">Scroll down and up to see different reveal animations</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="">
    <div class="row py-5">
      <div class="col-5 gs_reveal gs_reveal_fromLeft">
        <div class="d-block">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/479/479?index=1" alt="" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-7">
        <h2 class="gs_reveal">Create amazing svg animations</h2>
        <p class="gs_reveal">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis quia doloribus, inventore rem, at pariatur asperiores minus qui accusantium quod nisi! Modi eveniet eaque enim totam deserunt dolores alias aliquid.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row py-5">
      <div class="col-7 text-end">
        <h2 class="gs_reveal">Supercharge immersive WebGL experiences</h2>
        <p class="gs_reveal"> Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam praesentium numquam fugiat consequatur aliquid eos assumenda natus deserunt eum doloribus quia mollitia omnis, voluptatem maiores dicta exercitationem veritatis magnam iusto in
          officiis reiciendis ipsum, delectus maxime? Sit eligendi temporibus dolores? </p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-5 gs_reveal gs_reveal_fromRight">
        <div class="d-block">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/479/479?index=2" alt="" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row py-5">
      <div class="col-5 gs_reveal_fromLeft">
        <div class="block">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/479/479?index=3" alt="" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-7 text-start">
        <h2 class="gs_reveal">Control performant Canvas animations</h2>
        <p class="gs_reveal"> Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore nulla natus minus praesentium, adipisci quam distinctio recusandae accusamus similique aut velit iusto reprehenderit deleniti! Nobis?</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row py-5">
      <div class="col-7 text-end">
        <h2 class="gs_reveal">Award winning websites</h2>
        <p class="gs_reveal"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem vero temporibus deleniti qui rem ipsa! </p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-5 gs_reveal gs_reveal_fromRight">
        <div class="d-block">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/479/479?index=4" alt="" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `trigger.kill();` in the `onComplete` callback hook:

```js
function animateFrom(elem, direction) {
  direction = direction || 1;
  var x = 0,
    y = direction * 100;
  if (elem.classList.contains("gs_reveal_fromLeft")) {
    x = -100;
    y = 0;
  } else if (elem.classList.contains("gs_reveal_fromRight")) {
    x = 100;
    y = 0;
  }
  elem.style.transform = "translate(" + x + "px, " + y + "px)";
  elem.style.opacity = "0";
  gsap.fromTo(elem, {
    x: x,
    y: y,
    autoAlpha: 0
  }, {
    duration: 1.5,
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    autoAlpha: 1,
    ease: "expo",
    overwrite: "auto",
    onComplete: function() {
    ScrollTrigger.getAll().forEach((trigger) => { 
      if (elem === trigger.trigger) trigger.kill() 
    });

  }
  });
  
  
}

function hide(elem) {
  gsap.set(elem, {
    autoAlpha: 0
  });
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

  gsap.utils.toArray(".gs_reveal").forEach(function(elem) {
    hide(elem); // assure that the element is hidden when scrolled into view

    ScrollTrigger.create({
      trigger: elem,
       toggleActions: "play none none none",
      markers: false,
      onEnter: function() {
        animateFrom(elem)
      },
      // onEnterBack: function() { animateFrom(elem, -1) },
      // onLeave: function() { hide(elem) } // assure that the element is hidden when scrolled into view
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.gs_reveal {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  will-change: transform, opacity;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-SbiR/eusphKoMVVXysTKG/7VseWii+Y3FdHrt0EpKgpToZeemhqHeZeLWLhJutz/2ut2Vw1uQEj2MbRF+TVBUA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.11.5/gsap.min.js" integrity="sha512-cOH8ndwGgPo+K7pTvMrqYbmI8u8k6Sho3js0gOqVWTmQMlLIi6TbqGWRTpf1ga8ci9H3iPsvDLr4X7xwhC/+DQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.11.5/ScrollTrigger.min.js" integrity="sha512-AMl4wfwAmDM1lsQvVBBRHYENn1FR8cfOTpt8QVbb/P55mYOdahHD4LmHM1W55pNe3j/3od8ELzPf/8eNkkjISQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="py-5">
    <h1 class="gs_reveal text-center">Scroll down and up to see different reveal animations</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="">
    <div class="row py-5">
      <div class="col-5 gs_reveal gs_reveal_fromLeft">
        <div class="d-block">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/479/479?index=1" alt="" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-7">
        <h2 class="gs_reveal">Create amazing svg animations</h2>
        <p class="gs_reveal">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis quia doloribus, inventore rem, at pariatur asperiores minus qui accusantium quod nisi! Modi eveniet eaque enim totam deserunt dolores alias aliquid.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row py-5">
      <div class="col-7 text-end">
        <h2 class="gs_reveal">Supercharge immersive WebGL experiences</h2>
        <p class="gs_reveal"> Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam praesentium numquam fugiat consequatur aliquid eos assumenda natus deserunt eum doloribus quia mollitia omnis, voluptatem maiores dicta exercitationem veritatis magnam iusto in
          officiis reiciendis ipsum, delectus maxime? Sit eligendi temporibus dolores? </p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-5 gs_reveal gs_reveal_fromRight">
        <div class="d-block">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/479/479?index=2" alt="" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row py-5">
      <div class="col-5 gs_reveal_fromLeft">
        <div class="block">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/479/479?index=3" alt="" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-7 text-start">
        <h2 class="gs_reveal">Control performant Canvas animations</h2>
        <p class="gs_reveal"> Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore nulla natus minus praesentium, adipisci quam distinctio recusandae accusamus similique aut velit iusto reprehenderit deleniti! Nobis?</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row py-5">
      <div class="col-7 text-end">
        <h2 class="gs_reveal">Award winning websites</h2>
        <p class="gs_reveal"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem vero temporibus deleniti qui rem ipsa! </p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-5 gs_reveal gs_reveal_fromRight">
        <div class="d-block">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/479/479?index=4" alt="" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: In your example, on the first scroll, the last blocks are not even displayed. But I like this idea.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function animateFrom(elem, direction) {
  direction = direction || 1;
  var x = 0,
    y = direction * 100;
  if (elem.classList.contains("gs_reveal_fromLeft")) {
    x = -100;
    y = 0;
  } else if (elem.classList.contains("gs_reveal_fromRight")) {
    x = 100;
    y = 0;
  }
  elem.style.transform = "translate(" + x + "px, " + y + "px)";
  elem.style.opacity = "0";
  gsap.fromTo(elem, {
    x: x,
    y: y,
    autoAlpha: 0
  }, {
    duration: 1.5,
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    autoAlpha: 1,
    ease: "expo",
    overwrite: "auto",
    onComplete: function() {
    ScrollTrigger.getAll().forEach((trigger) => { 
      if (elem === trigger.trigger) trigger.kill() 
    });

  }
  });
  
  
}

function hide(elem) {
  gsap.set(elem, {
    autoAlpha: 0
  });
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

  gsap.utils.toArray(".gs_reveal").forEach(function(elem) {
    hide(elem); // assure that the element is hidden when scrolled into view

    ScrollTrigger.create({
      trigger: elem,
       toggleActions: "play none none none",
      markers: false,
      onEnter: function() {
        animateFrom(elem)
      },
      // onEnterBack: function() { animateFrom(elem, -1) },
      // onLeave: function() { hide(elem) } // assure that the element is hidden when scrolled into view
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.gs_reveal {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  will-change: transform, opacity;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-SbiR/eusphKoMVVXysTKG/7VseWii+Y3FdHrt0EpKgpToZeemhqHeZeLWLhJutz/2ut2Vw1uQEj2MbRF+TVBUA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.11.5/gsap.min.js" integrity="sha512-cOH8ndwGgPo+K7pTvMrqYbmI8u8k6Sho3js0gOqVWTmQMlLIi6TbqGWRTpf1ga8ci9H3iPsvDLr4X7xwhC/+DQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.11.5/ScrollTrigger.min.js" integrity="sha512-AMl4wfwAmDM1lsQvVBBRHYENn1FR8cfOTpt8QVbb/P55mYOdahHD4LmHM1W55pNe3j/3od8ELzPf/8eNkkjISQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="py-5">
    <h1 class="gs_reveal text-center">Scroll down and up to see different reveal animations</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="">
    <div class="row py-5">
      <div class="col-5 gs_reveal gs_reveal_fromLeft">
        <div class="d-block">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/479/479?index=1" alt="" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-7">
        <h2 class="gs_reveal">Create amazing svg animations</h2>
        <p class="gs_reveal">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis quia doloribus, inventore rem, at pariatur asperiores minus qui accusantium quod nisi! Modi eveniet eaque enim totam deserunt dolores alias aliquid.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row py-5">
      <div class="col-7 text-end">
        <h2 class="gs_reveal">Supercharge immersive WebGL experiences</h2>
        <p class="gs_reveal"> Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam praesentium numquam fugiat consequatur aliquid eos assumenda natus deserunt eum doloribus quia mollitia omnis, voluptatem maiores dicta exercitationem veritatis magnam iusto in
          officiis reiciendis ipsum, delectus maxime? Sit eligendi temporibus dolores? </p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-5 gs_reveal gs_reveal_fromRight">
        <div class="d-block">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/479/479?index=2" alt="" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row py-5">
      <div class="col-5 gs_reveal_fromLeft">
        <div class="d-block">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/479/479?index=3" alt="" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-7 text-start">
        <h2 class="gs_reveal">Control performant Canvas animations</h2>
        <p class="gs_reveal"> Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore nulla natus minus praesentium, adipisci quam distinctio recusandae accusamus similique aut velit iusto reprehenderit deleniti! Nobis?</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row py-5">
      <div class="col-7 text-end">
        <h2 class="gs_reveal">Award winning websites</h2>
        <p class="gs_reveal"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem vero temporibus deleniti qui rem ipsa! </p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-5 gs_reveal gs_reveal_fromRight">
        <div class="d-block">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/479/479?index=4" alt="" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: In your <container> you have 4 image <div> sections.
The "class" that you provided to the 1st, 2nd and 4th index image was... class="d-block"

The 3rd row has class="block" ... where is the d-  ??

I'm using Bootstrap5.3 CSS and there is NO ".block" class.
Line 7354 in Bootstrap@5.3 CSS shows
    .d-block {
    display: block !important;
    }

in which you have used correctly.  I think your GSAP animation in not performing consistently due to the miss-spelt class="d-block"   in which would cause some issues for the animations to consistently animate, whether scrolling up or down.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).